# SQL 'NOT IN' Operator doesn't give expected results when comparing columns in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to update a table from a temporary table. Therefore I need to compare and find out what lines are not in the main table to be imported from the temp table.
My tables look like follows,

```
line_id -> nvarchar(20)
order_no -> nvarchar(20)
line_no ->int
```

Both tables have same fields but the temp table has more up to date records to be brought to the main table. I am using;

```
INSERT INTO main_table
  SELECT * FROM temp_table t 
  WHERE t.line_id NOT IN (SELECT line_id FROM main_table)
```

But the condition  `WHERE t.line_id NOT IN (SELECT line_id FROM main_table)` doesn't bring any order lines.
But when `order_no` is used instead of `line_id`, the comparison is done and a number or order lines start to show up. But `order_no` is not an unique key and that comparison doesn't return all the lines needed.

It would be great if you could help me.. Thanking in advance!

Comment: Are there any line_id s that are in the temp table that are not in the main - note that insert only adds rows andcannot update anything

Comment: Yes, it is. There is no primary key in either of tables (not a good practise) but one non-indexable column returns results when none others does!

Comment: Mark - Yes, there are more than 1000 lines in temp which are not in main. I used the word 'update' with its literal meaning, not the technical meaning.. sorry about that :P

Comment: Not in will not work if any line_id is null - while `select 1 where 1 not in (2)` works, `select 1 where 1 not in (2, null)` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not-in's can give odd troubles. Here's a different spin on the same idea.

```
Insert Into main_table
  select t.* 
    from temp_table t
    left outer join main_Table m
      on t.line_id=m.line_id
   where m.line_id is null
```

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help you! Blessings!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO main_table
  SELECT * FROM temp_table t 
  WHERE LTRIM(RTRIMt.line_id)) NOT IN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(line_id)) FROM main_table)
```

Comment: I tried this but had no luck with it! I was so confused having no way to explain what was going on.